# Capitalization of words

Tags: capitalization

I am writing the following in a proper thesis write up, and have a question of whether I should capitalize the first word in each bullet point (i.e. 'e') or not?

The database contains a variety of information. They include:
1.  **e**ach manager’s profile,
2.  **e**ach asset's returns, and
3.  **e**ach asset's profile.

Comment: it's a matter of taste. I think I would.

Comment: Yes, captialize *Each*. But you can drop the punctuation at each line end, as well as *and* there.

Comment: Jenny, what does the word "they" refer to?  The database, variety, or information?

Answer (score 1):

Although @WS2 is correct that to a certain degree it's a matter of taste, if the bullets are complete sentences, you should capitalize them, but if they can be interpreted as part of a sentence, you should not. So, in the example you provide, they should not be capitalized.

From [Get It Write, Handling Vertical Lists](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/101406VerticalLists.htm):

> Except when the items in a list are complete sentences (or when they
>   contain complete sentences), treat a list as a single long sentence.

Additionally, as @michael_timofeev points out, I would change:

> The database contains a variety of information. They include:

to:

> The database contains a variety of information, including

Note that the colon is also unnecessary if the list is being interpreted as part of a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a slight modification to your example, and change "They include:"

The database contains a variety of information that includes the following:
1. each manager’s profile,
2. each asset's returns, and
3. each asset's profile.

I have changed it into a defining clause, which is better, and also follows the website's advice not to put the colon directly after the verb (include.)

As far as the capitalization is concerned, you can leave the es uncapitalized.  Look for Rule 3 on this page:
http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp